# multiresources GET /search API implemented with JSONAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

How would you implement a /search API that could return different resources with JSONAPI ?

`GET /search?q=london` could for example return an `author` resource for 'Jack London' and a `book` resource for 'London: The Novel'

I started doing this by implementing a `search` resource that would return included `book` and `author` resources but to follow JSONAPI, I'd have to refactor the API to `GET /search?filger[q]=london`

I have the feeling that this (quite common) usecase has not really been adressed by JSONAPI.

My final goal is to implement this with a Rails backend using JSONAPI::Resources and an ember app with ember-data

What would be your advice ?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use ember-data as is. You will likely need to   create a custom adapter to return the appropriate model type depending on the result from your server.

Comment: A wrapper model that hasMany books, hasMany author, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually using the [jsonapi-utils](https://github.com/b2beauty/jsonapi-utils) gem so that you could point the resource you would like to use for the serialization:

With the `jsonapi_serialize` method:

```
class SearchesController < BaseController
  def index
    results = MySearchEngine.search(params)
    render json: jsonapi_serialize(results, options: { resource: UserResource })
  end
end
```

Or the high-level `jsonapi_render` method:

```
class SearchesController < BaseController
  def index
    results = MySearchEngine.search(params)
    jsonapi_render json: results, options: { resource: UserResource }
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :search, only: [:show]

# app/controllers/searches_controller.rb
def show
  render json: Search.new(params).as_json
end

# app/classes/search.rb
class Search
  def initialize(params = {})
    @results = [
      Author.where(name: params[:q]),
      Book.where(title: params[:q]),
    ].flatten
  end

  def as_json
    serialized_resources =
      @results.map do |result|
        resource = JSONAPI::Resource.resource_for(result.model_name.singular)
        serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(resource)
        serializer.serialize_to_hash(resource.new(result, nil))[:data]
      end
    { data: serialized_resources }
  end
end
```

Surely, there's a better way?